# Failing to connect to mysql server when I change port number

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I attempted to change MYSQL container to run on a different port number ie **3307** in my docker-compose file but I get a database connection error as shown below after launching services with `docker-compose up` what could be the issue?

```
web_1         | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
web_1         |     self.connect()
web_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 194, in connect
web_1         |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
web_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 227, in get_new_connection
web_1         |     return Database.connect(**conn_params)
web_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 130, in Connect
web_1         |     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
web_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 185, in __init__
web_1         |     super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
web_1         | MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' (115)")
web_1         |
web_1         | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
web_1         |
web_1         | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
web_1         |     worker.init_process()
web_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
web_1         |     self.load_wsgi()
web_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
web_1         |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
web_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
web_1         |     self.callable = self.load()
web_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
web_1         |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
web_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
web_1         |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
web_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
web_1         |     __import__(module)
web_1         |   File "/src/core/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
web_1         |     application = get_wsgi_application()
web_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
web_1         |     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
web_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
web_1         |     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
web_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 120, in populate
web_1         |     app_config.ready()
web_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django_prometheus/apps.py", line 23, in ready
web_1         |     ExportMigrations()
web_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django_prometheus/migrations.py", line 49, in ExportMigrations
web_1         |     executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[alias])
web_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
web_1         |     self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
web_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
web_1         |     self.build_graph()
web_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 212, in build_graph
web_1         |     self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
web_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 61, in applied_migrations
web_1         |     if self.has_table():
web_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 44, in has_table
web_1         |     return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
web_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 255, in cursor
web_1         |     return self._cursor()
web_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 232, in _cursor
web_1         |     self.ensure_connection()
web_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
web_1         |     self.connect()
web_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
web_1         |     raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
web_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
web_1         |     self.connect()
web_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 194, in connect
web_1         |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
web_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 227, in get_new_connection
web_1         |     return Database.connect(**conn_params)
web_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 130, in Connect
web_1         |     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
web_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 185, in __init__
web_1         |     super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
web_1         | django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' (115)")
```

## Docker Compose File

```
  db:
    restart: always
    image: mysql:5.7

    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password

    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
      MYSQL_DATABASE: default_schema
      MYSQL_USER: test
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
      
    expose:
      - "3307"
    ports:
      - "3307:3307"

    volumes:
      - ../mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql


  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: pma
    links:
      - db
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      PMA_PORT: 3307
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8183:80
```

## Application DB Settings

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'default_schema',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'test',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': '3307',
    }
}
```

## After running `docker ps`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                         NAMES
2d60c0265ed9        nllb_frontend           "/docker-entrypoint.…"   7 seconds ago       Up 6 seconds        0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp                            frontend
323a7dd77121        nllb_web                "gunicorn --bind 0.0…"   7 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds        7000/tcp                                      nllb_web_1
89ad90d1fb10        phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   7 seconds ago       Up 6 seconds        0.0.0.0:8183->80/tcp                          pma
e5c5e2bda22c        mysql:5.7               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   8 seconds ago       Up 7 seconds        3306/tcp, 33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3307->3307/tcp   nllb_db_1
1332ad2e136b        redis:latest            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   9 seconds ago       Up 8 seconds        6379/tcp                                      nllb_redis_1
```

Comment: did you also change the port of the mysql server in the image? Currently you are exposing port 3307 from the container, but the mysql instance in the container is probably still listening to default port 3306

Comment: @derpirscher what is the name of the parameter that I'll add under environments to declare the port number  from the docker-compose file above ?

Comment: You should also allow that port through your firewall. That solved a similar problem i was facing with.

Comment: have a look at the documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installation-excerpt/5.7/en/environment-variables.html should be `MYSQL_TCP_PORT`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to also tell MySQL about the change of plans:

```
environment:
  MYSQL_TCP_PORT: 3307
```

(fixed, thanks to @derpirscher, see below)

(I previously guessed it would be `PORT`, `DB_PORT`, `MYSQL_PORT`, `MYSQLD_PORT`, or, as a testament to my willingness to believe any absurdity I find on Github, `MYSQL_HOST=db:3307`)

Comment: according to this document its MYSQL_TCP_PORT  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installation-excerpt/5.7/en/environment-variables.html

Comment: Hmmm, and yet there's also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_port, which is `mysqld_port` according to the url, but `port` according to the actual page. Shouldn't be too hard to try, though. @Philip: note that any value set in the configuration would overwrite the environmental var. I'ts unlikely to be set, but something to look for if tit doesn't work.

Comment: Added  `MYSQL_TCP_PORT: 3307` under environments it's working ;)

Answer (score 0):

Connections between containers always use the "normal" port number for the service; these connections ignore any remapping that `ports:` might do.  If you are only connecting to the database from another container, in fact, `ports:` isn't required at all; if it is present, the second port number again needs to be the "normal" port number for the service.

It should work to change the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    # do not need `expose:`
    ports:            # optional, if you're not going to connect from outside Docker
      - '3307:3306'   # second port _must_ be "normal" port 3306
  phpmyadmin:
    # do not need `container_name:` or `links:`
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db    # Compose service name
      PMA_PORT: 3306  # always the "normal" port, ignores `ports:`
```

And similarly in your configuration:

```python
'HOST': 'db',
'PORT': '3306',  # the "normal" port, ignores `ports:`
```

As I noted in comments, `expose:` and `links:` are only relevant for an outdated mode of Docker networking, and can be safely removed from the `docker-compose.yml` file.  There's also usually no harm in letting Compose pick its own `container_name:`.